# Did animals primarily evolve to differentiate UV-rich sky from UV-poor substrate OR did they evolve to see visible light?

Tags: evolution, vision, light

I read two things that appear to contradict each other.

1. The reason humans only see light in the visible spectrum is likely related to the transmission of light waves through water: most infrared and UV is absorbed by water while the range of light we see transmits very well through water, since we evolved in the sea it makes sense that we evolved this way.
2. The basal colour sense in all animals is UV and a green (or mid-wavelength) sensitivity. These are used to differentiate the UV-rich sky (or open space) from substrate which reflects UV poorly.

How can UV be a basal colour sense of all animals when all animals supposedly evolved in the sea and thus evolved to see light primarily in the visible spectrum?

Comment: What makes you think that the sense of vision cannot evolve further? This happened between 400 - 500 mio years ago, which is a long time, even if you think in evolutionary timespans.

Comment: I know vision can evolve further, it's just that the the two points were presented as explanations for the initial evolution of colour vision in all animals. One predicts UV is one of the primary spectral sensitivities to evolve, the other predicts it is only visible light since UV isn't transmitted well through water.